# Weierstrass points of discrete Riemann surfaces

Tags: co.combinatorics, riemann-surfaces

Is there a notion of Weierstrass points for  discrete Riemann surfaces?

Any help or reference would be welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: What is a "discrete Riemann surface"?  Do you mean a tropical curve?

Comment: #Jason Starr: no. I refer to another notion, cf. (for instance) "*Discrete Riemann surface*" by C. Mercat, in Handbook of Teichmuller Theory I. If I'm not wrong, the answer is yes for tropical curves